# What does Horse Strength do?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Horses have 4 stats: Strength, Speed, Stamina, and Temperament.

Speed and Stamina are pretty straight forward. Speed, is well, how fast you can go, and stamina decides the number of times you can boost the speed before it has to rest. Temperament is explained [in this Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304747/162442).

But what does Strength do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the information collected in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/61g977/botw_horse_strength_hp_testing_results/), it appears that the Strength stat of a horse does, indeed, affect how much HP it has.

> Don't ask how the science was done. :'/
>
> - 1 star ~ 60hp or two hits with a lvl 30 weapon
> - 2 star ~ 120hp or four hits with a lvl 30 weapon
> - 3 star ~ 180 hp or six hits with a lvl 30 weapon
> - 4 star ~ 240hp or eight hits with a lvl 30 weapon
> - 5 star ~ 300hp or ten hits with a lvl 30 weapon
>
> Boarding your horse resets the strength as does taking it out from another stable. Hope this helps.
>
> Note: Only 2, 4, and 5 star strength horses were used in this study. 1 and 3 stars were extrapolated using complex mathematical models.

Comment: well combining the above mentioned test with the 30 dmg weapon and my tests with a 50 damage weapon, id say it makes a lot of sense that each star = 50hp.