# What are the Horses' Temperaments, and what do they change?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

[image: horse with gentle temperament]

Horses have a temperament stat like in the image above, where the horse's temperament is Gentle.

What are the different temperaments? What do they change about your horse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to articles like [this one](http://www.shacknews.com/article/99242/zelda-breath-of-the-wild---how-to-tame-horses), a horse's temperament affects how easily a horse is tamed:

> How hard it is to tame a horse in Breath of the Wild depends on which horse you’re trying to tame. Some horses have a gentle temperament, meaning they’ll almost immediately calm down when you attempt to tame them. Some horses have a more wild personality which means it’ll take some stamina to hold on long enough to be able to ride them.

[This article](http://www.gameskinny.com/rs233/breath-of-the-wild-guide-horse-taming-101) also indicates this:

> Remember: unicolored horses have the highest stats, **but they also have the worst temperament. That means it'll be harder for you to get control without getting bucked off.** Each "soothing" session stacks with the last one, so if you continue hunting the same horse you can eventually tame it using sheer stubbornness.

Additionally, this article points out that a bad temperament means your horse will be more likely to disobey you, even after taming it:

> The more stubborn the temperament, the more likely it will disobey your commands.

As for the different types of temperaments, I'm only seeing Gentle and Wild (as those are set temperaments for a couple horses), but I believe there are others.

Comment: Wild horses will also buck you off immediately if you try to spur them on empty. Gentle horses will do nothing.